# How to connect to SQL Server hosted on Docker in Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine

I have installed SQL Server 2019 docker on Azure Ubuntu VM. The container is up and running. However, I cannot connect to it using SSMS from outside the VM. While running the container I used port 1450 to map to 1433. Also, I have configured the NSG to allow the traffic.
Still, I have no luck.

[image]

[image]

iptables -L
[image]

NSG
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To run SQL Server through Docker on Ubuntu, you can follow the steps here:

1. Pull the docker image to your Ubuntu host:

   `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu`
2. run the image through the docker command:

   `docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=azureUser@2018' -p 1450:1433 -d --name mssql mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu`
3. check the container if it runs well, you do this through the docker command:

   `sudo docker exec -it mssql /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
      -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'`
4. open the port 1450 in the NSG associated with your VM
5. connect the SQL Server through the SSMS like this:
   [image]

Note: If you open the firewall in the Ubuntu VM, you also need to open the port in the firewall.

You can find the Docker image information in [Microsoft SQL Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server?tab=description) and more details about [Run && Connect the SQL Server image with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash).

Update:

When you check the NSG rules, I suggest you can go into the VM networking, it will show all the NSGs that associated with the subnet and NIC. If allow port, you should add the rule to both NSG or change the NSG as the same, then you can just add the rule to only one NSG. Check the NSG rule as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This what exactly I did. I can connect the SQL server locally from the Ubuntu. However, not from outside vm

Comment: @user1716729 Do you add the NSG rule to allow the port 1450 with the VM? I can connect it outside.

Comment: @user1716729 OK, when you input the server name in the SSMS, there is a comma between the IP and the port, are you?

Comment: @user1716729 Maybe you can change the source with value any of NSG rule for port 1450. Also, you can check if there are rules in the machine block the traffic.

Comment: @user1716729 Any more update for what you did to run the SQL Server on Docker in the VM?

Comment: @user1716729 What other steps do you do? You can try to change the NSG rule with port 1450 as the source any.

Comment: I dropped the whole VM for a fresh start.. will let you know if I get the same error..

Comment: Recreated the vm, installed docker but no luck. Please see the updated post

Comment: Sorted. NSG was not associated to subnet

Comment: @user1716729 I update the answer for how to check the NSG rules. There is no problem that connects the SQL server container outside the VM.

Comment: @user1716729 Do you solve the problem with the update? Or any more update?